# Spring4 JUnit tests : Load SQL to a H2 db

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to write tests for a Spring Boot (Spring 4) Application.

My Junit test class is configured like this to allow autowired.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringApp.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
...
```

My `src/main/resources/application.properties` is like this

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb
spring.datasource.username=BNF0016779
spring.datasource.password=
```

In test context, src/test/resources/application.properties is just empty.

In can query the db as usual, creating objects...

But I'd like to create a data init sql.

To begin with a strange behavior, It seems that Spring loads any "schema.sql" in classpath.
Something like the following is not required ?

```
//This is not required to execute schema.sql
@Configuration
public class DatabaseTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Then, I can't create any Table from this SQL.
Always receive `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MY_TABLE" already exists; SQL statement:`

H2 is supposed to be a in-memory DB, no keeping data between two startup !
Why do I receive these errors ?

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Boot will in fact execute a file named `schema.sql` in the root of the classpath by default. Furthermore, Spring Boot will also automatically create an embedded database for your application unless you instruct it otherwise. Consult the "[Initialize a database using Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)" section of the Spring Boot reference manual for details.

> H2 is supposed to be a in-memory DB, no keeping data between two
>   startup !

Yes and no.

If Spring Boot creates an embedded H2 database for you, yes it will be *in-memory*.

However, the database is actually a bean in the `ApplicationContext` (just like any other Spring-managed component). Thus it *lives* as long as the `ApplicationContext` lives, and the *Spring TestContext Framework* caches contexts between tests: that's one of its main features. In other words, the embedded database will **not** be recreated between tests (unless you annotate your test classes or test methods with `@DirtiesContext`). Consult the [Context caching](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) section of the Spring Framework reference manual for details.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

H2 can be in memory. But I'm assuming the default `DataSource` it uses is not.

You can set the `DataSourceFactory` on the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` to generate a `DataSource` that connects with a url such as `jdbc:h2:mem:test`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, by default, it's in memory

Comment: Yeah, just checked grepcode for the 4.1.3.RELEASE and it is in memory by default, my bad